# Whats is the difference for React between this two things and their types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In Typescript/React i'm currently working on some types.

What is the difference between call `<Comp/>` and `Comp`, for React or/and Javascript ?

```js
const Comp = () => { 
  return (
   <svg ...props/> 
  )
}

const data = {
  title: 'foo',
  icon: Comp
}

const data2 = {
  title: 'foo',
  icon: <Comp/>
}
```

And what is the type for `icon` ? Currently `ElementType` is working, but i don't know what does it mean ?

Would me explain me this ?
Thanks in advance !

```
export type Test = {
  title: string;
  icon: ElementType (but why ?)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Comp/>` creates an *instance* of the `Comp` component: A React element, ready to be used in a render. `Comp` is just a reference to the component function. Which you want depends on how you intend to use it.

If you intend to just use it directly (I suspect you do in that specific example):

```
return <divOrWhatever>{data.icon}</divOrWhatever>;
```

...*(`divOrWhatever` is just for context)* then you want `<Comp/>`. Normally when you're accepting content of that kind, you'd use the `ReactNode` type (which is a union of `ReactElement | string | number | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`), but you could use `ReactElement` if you want to disallow fragments, strings, etc.

Here's an example (I've commented out the types, but [here's a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcARFATIwNwBQnaEAdgGd4QlFDgBeJiRQwUALlAoA5kgD0YPkvYAjFAKQA2ACyZgANQBCAeQQB3AAwBpAOJKIAQU-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) to the TypeScript playground with the types intact):

```js
const star = "data:image/png;base64,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";

/*
interface ExampleProps {
    icon: ReactNode;
}
*/

const Example = ({icon}/*: ExampleProps*/) => {
    return <div>{icon}</div>;
};

const Comp = () => {
    return <img src={star}/>;
};

const App = () => {
    return <Example icon={<Comp/>} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you intend to use it as a component function, then I'd suggest `Icon` rather than `icon`, and the usage would look like this:

```
const { Icon } = data;
return <divOrWhatever><Icon /></divOrWhatever>;
```

In that case, the type is `() => ReactElement` or `(props: {}) => ReactElement` or similar, since the component takes no props.

Here's an example ([with types on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHbwC+cAZlBCHAERQEwsDcAUD2hAoBneCJRQ4AXlYATFDBQAuUCgDmSAPRgKqrgCMUQpADYALJmAA1AEIB5BAHcADAGkA4qogBBH14ByAMoAqgAWhEGqvtamvl5IAMJeAJqxAOwAsi7GwLHxABrWAJIA6nnpvkIAKr4AMoQOhF7gDik+1pVOxIQAipYIphR+xcUAbkEQACLdCAEAYgAKDukI8RoAHHpCESHpScAAjIWzwCW2qjXxEwBaAFLsXhMuy24BtulQANQ+AI4ATIXAWYwEbeeLEKB6MDWPSEGTxb7AFxLADM6UKlSuVyQdFsqQA1l5bBRbMYkB81gAJGS49JTYwhBBoPLdACcXnmSAAHhBuiMvBSAKw+FlXABWqkKpkIKApayShHm+x0nP2ou6AFdVHkYOrOYQJjiHF4YL9bF48pyAF6qAWpFwhAIOAUQZFrGDELzpJBeNwoeLVJACwqilCDKBBZGqCZIELEPxeAX7Sqc1R6Pw6BDGG5JdFoBAyfamIKW6yWACelniNSc1iuUHmbhGqhka1mDlFazxVx1N3Sa2ReQcswSnNgICEHzLbiCTjBDgp3RQLOIZZg3QFeLyE2Mor8V2Iqkt3TcGgpIHatn2a0ISFma05dbODkhlVUbhZEwgSHmXjADhqaw3Gg6pgPsICpG4v7-E4nJ6PMVxDMYAQTCAejGPsaaGN8VzzCycLfGsEwLhMfiWmAQSmKkKDAN6fYyPM3R0Hk-YIM6ThCGWCC-N0FJIFAMhlsU1gUA43xJHQfi-FAFAUHiKBgDcNxgIUSDIm4BI1N88TAGWsxoMQbhIN03S6fMEAUvUcohJY3S2CEGiNLEwSWPYLgCvEOaFJI3B8MAVB8XQ6BIHAhCcig4CkPMjBgEIuA8HACVwIUAgUIocAABQAJRSAAfPg6AwCQZCUDAAA8oZltgFU5bw1B8ClIghWFEXBdI6V4MlghwNQaWheFYCRdFQjZZIeU4PFiXsDq0lwKVMjACMOWlZ1FBwBoS0aPNi21bw-CCI18RMGAUgZSNY0TQlU3qjNpWgKocBCFAaCSDgYhQLQ607fV+3wL+x1tWdcWJXAV03X1LVJSlL2HeAH01Tw1BcEAA)):

```js
const star = "data:image/png;base64,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";

/*
interface ExampleProps {
    Icon: () => ReactElement<any, any>;
}
*/

const Example = ({ Icon }/*: ExampleProps*/) => {
    return <div><Icon /></div>;
};

const Comp = () => {
    return <img src={star} />;
};

const App = () => {
    return <Example Icon={Comp} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```